# Skilled migrant category job search visa NZ

Tags: new-zealand

Yesterday, I have received an invite to apply for SMC job search visa and i have only 12 months. Need to complete visa arrangements within in next 3 months and after that I have to meet the skilled employment.
They asked to send some documents alongwith the passport, however, they haven't mentioned where to send. I saw they mentioned that case office will contact you but I have not received any revert after many follow-ups but my clock already started.
Can someone guide how can I apply and where please ?

Comment: Who invited you? The official NZ website https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/skilled-migrant-category-resident-visa says *Selections for expressions of interest are suspended until further notice*

Comment: That the email(s) you received present significantly incomplete information suggests that the source is a non-governmental business, a visa "agent" or "service" that hopes you'll pay for assistance. Developed-country (US, Canada, UK, Australia, EU, NZ, etc) visa processes do not require aftermarket agents or services. The common and accepted advice here is to avoid them, as they are unnecessary, add no value, and sometimes present out-of-date information and advice.